# How to check if lable is not empty?

Tags: java, label

How to check if label is empty and clean?

Comment: One sec` i need to think how to explain it

Comment: @YoavLevavi post some code. for it

Comment: The text of label1 = "Hello" and this text was defined after getting text from textField and then if he clicked enter and changed the text in the textfield so i want that the label won`t be changed. I hope i explained my self good :)

Comment: @YoavLevavi so label can jut change once and that is all? so user have one attempt?

Comment: @u r welcome, i am trying to see what I can do

Comment: @YoavLevavi I posted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
    JFrame f = new JFrame("Demo");
    f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    f.setSize(300, 200);
    f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    //put the frame at the center of your monitor  
    f.setLocationRelativeTo(null); 
    JTextField userText = new JTextField(6);
    JLabel label = new JLabel();
    JButton button = new JButton("OK");


    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
            if (label.getText().isEmpty()) {
                label.setText(userText.getText());
            }
        }
    });


    f.add(userText);
    f.add(button);
    f.add(label);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

`addActionListener` in `Java 8` is

```
button.addActionListener((ActionEvent ae) -> {
            if (label.getText().isEmpty()) {
                label.setText(userText.getText());
            }
        });
```

**Explanation:**

You check if label contains any string, so if it is empty it means it is the first time and you have not set any text in it yet.If it is not empty, you have already had any text inside the label,so you cannot enter any text inside the label any more because the if statement can not be satisfied and the label does not get edited.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is good because it is simple. Creating a blank text label then setting it at a later point is useless because it will look exactly the same as creating and setting it at the same time. Add this inside if your actionPerformed().

```
final JLabel label = new JLabel(textFieldVariable.getText());
//Attributes for label here
```